# jquery.get() ajax call not being called

Tags: jquery

What is wrong with my code? Its not doing any call at all. I even tried adding errors into the php file and nothing happened, so its clearly not calling it. And yes, I've already checked the path many times and its correct.

The button does work though, it changes the h1 tag to green when clicked on.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search-button").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("h1").css('background-color', 'green');
            var word = $("#searchbar").val();
            $.get("video/search_videos.php", {searchword:word},
                function(title) 
                {
                    $("h1").html(title);
                    $("h1").css("background-color", "red");
                },
                "json");
        });
    });
```

Comment: What's the fiddler2 traffic look like?

Comment: Run fiddler, then execute the GET request. It should tell you alot.

Comment: I did and id didn't change the h1 tag. But should it have if it has no access to my php file?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eLSDN/ here's the js fiddle

Comment: Not jsFiddle, Fiddler Web Debugger. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19241/discussion-between-user1015214-and-asawyer)

Answer (score 0):

The function passed in in `$.get` is the callback function after success AJAX call.
It means that the function only will be executed if you ajax call is success.

However, you may failed to make the AjaxCall

Try to add a `ajaxError()` print out the error.

```
        $("#log").ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, exception) {
        alert(jqXHR.status);
        });
```

Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) for more details